# Need help in scraping the img src from a website; below is my code

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is my web scraping code for a website; it clicks a form which redirects to a page. From that page I need to extract [img] src url and export it into csv in a text form. I used the code below to extract a content from a td tag. When I run the same code it doesn't work because the td tag has no content but only a img tag. Any help will be appreciated. I am new to web-scraping. Thanks in Advance.

browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".textinput[value='APPLY']").click()

```
#select_finder = "//tr[contains(text(), 'NB')]//a"
            select_finder = "//td[text()='NB')]/../td[2]/a"
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".content a").click()

            assert "Application Details" in browser.title
            file_data = []

            try:
                assert "Application Details" in browser.title

                enlargement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[15]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/b").text
                enlargement_answer1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[15]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]").text
                enlargement_answer2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[15]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]").text
                enlargement_text = enlargement + enlargement_answer1 + enlargement_answer2

                considerations = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/b").text
                considerations_answer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]").text
                considerations_text = considerations + considerations_answer

                alteration = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]/b").text
                alteration_answer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[4]/td[7]").text
                alteration_text = alteration + alteration_answer

                units = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/b").text
                units_answer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[15]/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]").text
                units_text = units + units_answer

                occupancy = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]/b").text
                occupancy_answer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]").text
                occupancy_text = occupancy + occupancy_answer

                coo = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/b").text
                coo_answer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[7]/td[4]").text
                coo_text = coo + coo_answer

                floors = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/b").text
                floors_answer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table[16]/tbody/tr[8]/td[4]").text
                floors_text = floors + floors_answer

            except (NoSuchElementException, AssertionError) as e:
                floors_text.append("No Zoning Characteristics Present")
                coo_text.append("n/a")
                occupancy_text.append("n/a")
                units_text.append("n/a")
                alteration_text.append("n/a")
                considerations_text.append("n/a")
                enlargement_text.append("n/a")


            with open('DOB.csv', 'a') as f:
                wr = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
                wr.writerow((block_number, lot_number, houseno, street, condo_text,
                             vacant_text, city_owned_text, file_data, floors_text, coo_text, occupancy_text, units_text, alteration_text,
                              considerations_text, enlargement_text ))

            browser.close()
```

Comment: Can you add the html that shows what you are trying to get

Comment: <tr>
  <td class="content"></td>
  <td class="content">
  
  <img src="images/box_check.gif" height="10" width="10">
  
  </td>
  <td class="label" colspan="5">
  
   
   Alteration Type 1  
   
  
  </td>
 </tr>
@Ywapom thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you are new to web scraping I encourage you to read up a bit: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
You are using XPath exclusively and in ways that are not recommended.

From the docs: "You can use XPath to either locate the element in absolute terms (not advised), or relative to an element that does have an id or name attribute."
Try using other locators to get your image.
for example: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src='images/box_check.gif']")`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The link was really helpful and may work for me. One doubt that I have is that on my original code I could specify which table, tr and td to look for content in. How do I mention which table and row to look in your code? The website I am scrapping has multiple tables and row which are unnamed. @Ywapom

Comment: I'd have to see more of the html to say.  Keep trying different things. You might use find_elements (plural) to get a list of elements and then loop through them to find what you want.  And if the answer is useful vote it up.

Comment: The link is  http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?requestid=3&passjobnumber=122433937&passdocnumber=01 
I am trying to get table 9 Additional Considerations, Limitations or Restrictions.
@Ywapom

Comment: You can loop through a pattern of getting a table, then its rows, then its cells and look at some attribute of the cells to match on.  Here is an example: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/selenium-webdriver-c-and-accessing-rows-in-a-table